# Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, ID: 0 while deserizing hazelcast map object

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

I have simple object with two field which extending the hazelcast DataSerializable interface. putting in that map working fine but while retrieving with same name its showing an exception says : 'Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, ID: 0'.

I am using hazelcast client '3.12.4' and hazelcast cluster with latest docker base image.

Please let me know guys if anyone of you faced the similar issue? I have not used any db as of now for simplicity purpose. my hazelcast client only saves a simple object in IMap and then retrieving from IMap.

Please find my code snippet below:

Domain Object:

```java
public class Employee implements DataSerializable {

    private String name;
    private Integer serialNumber;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, Integer serialNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    ** Getter and Setter **

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.name = in.readUTF();
        this.serialNumber = (Integer) in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(name);
        out.writeInt(serialNumber);
    }
```

Hazelcast save and get:

```java
IMap<String, Employee> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("employee");
        map.put(employee.getName(), employee);

EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
        Predicate predicate = e.get("serialNumber").lessThan(200);

Collection<Employee> result = map.values(predicate);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does your class have a default constructor ? Hazelcast has to create the object before running the `readData` method of `DataSerializable` to populate the fields. If you can post the class definition or even an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be helpful

Comment: @NeilStevenson I am using the default constructor in my domain object.Please find the code snippet in my post for more details.

Comment: Does `IMap.get(key)` work ? You're doing a search so need the domain model on the serverside, see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker#extending-classpath-with-new-jars-or-files

Comment: @NeilStevenson when I am trying to get the map value by key,Its working fine. Above mentioned exception I am getting while this predicate trying to fetch serialNumber less than 200 and and after that map.values are getting called.

Do you mean that this domain model class should be there in my cluster side also ?

Comment: Yes, for `DataSerializable` the domain model needs to be available serverside in order for the search to examine each record to determine if it is a match or not. Can you try adding the domain model to the classpath of the Docker container and report back ?

Comment: Any luck ? If you don’t want domain classes on the server swap from DataSerializable to Portable. You’ll need a PortableFactory but don’t need classes for the servers to do your query on intrinsic fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment dialogue, the answer here seems to be two-fold

`map.get(k)` works fine, so the serialization logic itself appears to correct.

In order to query `DataSerializable` objects, the domain objects need to be on the classpath of the server. The server must fully deserialise each object of that type to determine if it matches against the query predicate. The requires the docker container's classpath extended using the "`-e CLASSPATH`" option.